# Is there a way to hide the price on a product using Drupal Commerce?

Tags: 7, commerce

Basically I want to create a commerce site, load all the products but not give a price yet, for competitive reasons.

Instead of displaying 0 I want to:

1. Change the price to - "Call for price"
2. Hide add to cart button

At a later stage when I give the item a price it should:

1. Display the price
2. Display add to cart button

I know this is possible in Magento but would rather try using Drupal Commerce.
Any tutorials or links will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess giving the product a price is a manual process.

To make things clear I suggest adding a 'price hidden' boolen field to the product content type. Based on this field you can adjust the output of the product by implementing [hook_node_view_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7).

Answer (score 0):

With [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) you can use a drag & drop interface to hide the price and add-to-cart button by clicking on *manage display* for the product display content type. You can also create a *code field* for the *call now* button (if you don't want to use a custom template) by going to *Structure -> Display Suite -> Fields -> Add a code field* and that will then also be available on the drag & drop manage display screen.

Comment: I want to hide/disable price and cart. The user will request for more info if he is interested in the product. Can I do it with paragraphs module?