# Hide Price by Role for a Content Type in Drupal 7

Tags: commerce, entities

I am trying to achieve the following:
1> Hide Price Field for a Role only on a specific content type.

I am using Drupal Commerce.

Things I tried:
1> Field Permissions for the commerce_price field on a product. But because we using the same field across all product types the settings do not apply  to  just 1 product type.

2> preprocess_node
But could not access the price componenet. As it is a component inside the product reference field.

Could you please help me figure this out. Any help would be really appreciated!!

Links referred:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1496450
[Is there a way to hide the price on a product using Drupal Commerce?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37454/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-price-on-a-product-using-drupal-commerce?newreg=73623715c3ef4b97918f19112b6ddd4d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used Drupal Commerce, however I understand that you want to hide a field according to a role. That is doable through hook_field_access().

```
hook_field_access($op, $field, $entity_type, $entity, $account)
```

> Determine whether the user has access to a given field. This hook is
>   invoked from field_access() to let modules block access to operations
>   on fields. If no module returns FALSE, the operation is allowed.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_access/7

Comment: Thank you for the quick revert. I really appreciate that.
 As i would also need the node type information..I should include this function inside of node alter hook or pre process node hook right ?

Comment: Which function?The hook_field_access()? The field is attached to an entity, which is passed as input in the hook_field_access, so you can check info through $entity and $entity_type. More info are included in the hook's documentation.